# gcc auto correcting format in printf

Tags: c, gcc

I am using gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4 and compiling following code:

```
void main()
{
float f= 10.0;
char *str = "hello";
printf("f=%.1f str=%s\n",str, f);
}
```

Compiler is showing Warning that is expected:

```
prac.c: In function 'main':
prac.c:8:1: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
 printf("f=%.1f str=%s\n",str, f);
 ^
prac.c:8:1: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
```

However, while executing this program, output is auto-corrected.

```
# ./a.out
f=10.0 str=hello
```

How this is happening. 
Which feature of compiler is doing this.
Any way to disable this auto-correction.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour == Undefined Behaviour. (It's nothing to do with the compiler, and there is no "auto correction" - it's just a fluke of the ABI.)

Comment: @PaulR: Roll credits.

Answer (score 4):

That's not "auto correction," it's "undefined behavior."  It's happening because floating-point variables may be (or may not be!) passed to functions in a separate space vs. integral types.  So when you pass one pointer (or int) and one double, they are still using the first slot for each type, even though you specified them in the wrong order.

Compile with `-Wformat=2` and `-Werror` and you will never see this problem again, because GCC (and Clang) will refuse to build such code.

Comment: "*or may not be!*" -- Indeed, the same code would not work if compiled for 32-bit x86.